# Canvas drawing dashed line with arrow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I use the following code to draw a line with a arrow.
My problem is that i want to have the line dashed but not the arrow top:

```
function canvas_arrow_alternate2(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 12;   // length of head in pixels
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);

    context.setLineDash([10]);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.setLineDash([0]);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
}
```

The output now is a arrow which is not dashed.
The problem is the change of the "setLineDash".
How can i said that

```
context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
context.lineTo(tox, toy);
```

use

```
context.setLineDash([10]);
```

and the code later not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a path with that level of accuracy : when you either fill or stroke, the current settings (strokeStyle, fillStyle, font for fillText/strokeText immediate functions, lineDash, globalAlpha...) will be used to draw all the sub-path you built since last beginPath().
So for instance you couldn't build a yellow-red-blue-... line, with several lineTo and change in strokeStyle, then stroke() it at once : it would be drawn with the last color you set.

So in you case, you have to draw your arrow in two passes : the (untested) code below will hopefully help you find a way :

```
function canvas_arrow_alternate2(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy, strokeStyle){
    var headlen = 12;   // length of head in pixels
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
    context.save();    
    context.strokeStyle=strokeStyle || '#000'; // defaults to black
    // dashed part
    context.beginPath();
    context.setLineDash([10]);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.stroke();
    // second part -non dashed-
    context.beginPath();
    context.setLineDash([0]);
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
    context.stroke();
    // 
    context.restore();          // this will, in fact, restore strokeStyle
}
// notice you can get rid of save/restore if all your drawing methods sets the color before drawing.
```

Be sure (maybe you do) to use beginPath() to begin... well... each new Path, otherwise all draw commands will pile-up and all get executed on each stroke() or fill(), leading to a slow down.